# Errai and portlet deployment

Tags: gwt, liferay, portlet, portal, errai

This is my first question, for which I didn't find any answers in the web. The problem is, when using errai in portal environment, you'll get Exceptions on server side like this:

```
/out.50694-4048.erraiBus generates exception: null
```

and on client side like this:

```
GET http://myserver:8080/user/admin/in.20679-27603.erraiBus?z=1 404 (Not Found)
GET http://myserver:8080/user/admin/in.20679-27603.erraiBus?z=2 404 (Not Found)
GET http://myserver:8080/user/admin/in.20679-27603.erraiBus?z=3 404 (Not Found)
```

The reason for this is, that errai calls urls which are relative to the gwt module and not the web context name. Solution follows.
Same problems on other forums:

http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12383627?_19_threadView=flat

https://community.jboss.org/thread/177590?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a script in the html host page, like described in [Client Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Client+Configuration) in the errai docu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  erraiBusApplicationRoot = "/MyWebContextName";
</script>
```

This will solve all errai communication problems.